# sed: -e expression #1, char 10: extra characters after command

Tags: sed

I would like to take the first 2 lines from test.txt:

```
hello
my 
name
is
```

and put them at the top of a new file, output.txt:

```
foo
bar
```

with the desired output being, output.txt:

```
hello 
my
foo
bar
```

using sed. However, using:

```
text=$(head test.txt -n 2) | sed -i "1i $text" output.txt
```

returns the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: extra characters after command
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side by side or as is? And I don't really get why you need to use `sed` as a simple `>` would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you don't have to use pipe between the variable assignment `text=` and the `sed` command. You need to replace with the command delimiter `;`.

Second, you can get the error because part of the replacement text is interpreted by `sed`.
You actually need to quote the replacement string. This can be done with the `bash` parameter expansion operator `@Q`.

```
text=$(head -n2 test.txt)
sed -i "1i ${text@Q}" output.txt
```

As mentioned in the `bash` man pages:

> ${parameter@operator}
>   ...
>   Q     The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

Obviously inserting before line 1 is the same as doing:

```
head -n2 text.txt > /tmp/temp.txt
cat output.txt >> /tmp/temp.txt && mv /tmp/temp.txt ouput.txt
```

Comment: +1 just for that fancy `${text@Q}` thingy.

Comment: I tried `text=$(head -n2 test.txt)`
`sed -i "1i ${text@Q}" output.txt`
`cat output.txt `
`$'hello
my '
foo
bar    `
get this $ and ' in the output.txt fle

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding shell variables altogether:

- with `ed`

  ```
  printf '0r !head -n2 test.txt\nwq\n' | ed -s output.txt
  ```
- with `sed` (slightly more complicated, since the `r` command doesn't allow address `0`)

  ```
  head -n 2 test.txt | sed -i -e '1{h;r /dev/stdin' -e 'd;}' -e '2{H;x;}' output.txt
  ```

Comment: Both work I tried.

Answer (score 0):

- Append to the end of file

  ```
  head -n2 test.txt >> output.txt
  ```
- Append to the beginning of file @steeldriver's works

Comment: because that will replace the entire file rather than attaching the values to the top of the new file

Comment: Thanks [sam](https://askubuntu.com/users/692431/sam). Corrected.